# Integrate redis with flask application using redis-py

Tags: flask, redis, token

I want to use `redis-py` directly to work with flask, instead of other wrapper lib (e.g. `flask-redis`, `flask-and-redis`) of flask plugins. How to initialize redis-client in factory function `create_app()` of flask application ? Or how to properly just initialize `redis.StrictRedis` (maybe not compatible with other flask plugins of redis ??) ? Because there're some operations related to token persistence in router of other modules using this `redis.StrictRedis` object.

Any advice, please ?

Comment: Is there anyone can explain clearly about ***PRO and CON*** of `redis-py ` and other redis wrapper of flask plugins ? I met some leverage like this before, e.g. **`pure sqlalchemy` vs `flask-sqlalchemy`** and I chose `pure sqlalchemy` to work with flask for more flexibility with some non-web modules. Any likewise comments, please ?

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, I think using the wrappers may make things easier but if you just want to use redis as a cache you can very easily import redis and just create/instantiate alongside the flask app.

```
import redis
from flask import Flask

# make redis
redis_cache = redis.StrictRedis()

# make flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

# business logic 
@app.route('/<string:item>')
def index(item):
  # if cache hit then get from redis
  if redis_cache.exists(item):
     value = redis_cache.get(item)
  # cache miss
  else:
     value = 'Not in cache'
  return value
```

This is the simplest way.

You can also follow this [link](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/) to create the setup function and add the redis instantiation in the `create_app` function.